# How to efficiently rearrange elements in big data file?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I have this [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/opds8ptbr8c2rau/LargData1.dat?dl=0) and would like to rearrange the element in a specific way, I used `Table` but it tasks time `12 sec`, is this reasonable or there are different ways to do that

```
data=Get["https://www.dropbox.com/s/opds8ptbr8c2rau/LargData1.dat?dl=1"];

extrct = Table[
    Table[data[[i, j]], {i, 1, 4501}], {j, 1, 61}]; // AbsoluteTiming
    
 {11.7051, Null}
```

Comment: Can you describe the rearrangement you want to do? The code you showed does nothing (i.e. `extrct == data` with the data in your attached file).

Comment: This is what I did: I imported your data from the `LargData.dat` file you attached, assigned its contents to `data` (`data = Get[LargData.dat]`) and then ran your code. Then I ran `extrct == data` and obtained `True`, which indicates to me that `data` and `extrct` are identical after the Table. What should have happened instead?

Comment: Sorry I uploaded the wrong data file. kindly check now

Comment: `extrct = data[[1;;4501,1;;61]]`, is it what you try to achieve?

Comment: @yarchik, No, kindly check the updated data. you can see that `extrct [[1]]` not the same as `data[[1]]`

Comment: Maybe add `Transpose` then

Comment: `extrct==Transpose[data]` gives `True` and it takes only a few milliseconds.

Comment: @valarmorghulis everybody dies, including this question that I'm voting to close.

Comment: I know, it was a trivial question!

Comment: @valarmorghulis for next time, Dropbox links normally end in `?dl=0`, but if you change to `?dl=1` you get the data directly for download instead of the download page. That change makes the link suitable to use with `Import` or `Get`. Please, next time include the code necessary to import your data as well as the link.

Comment: @rhermans, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest answer is to use [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html)

[image]

```
data=Get["https://www.dropbox.com/s/opds8ptbr8c2rau/LargData1.dat?dl=1"];

extrct = Table[
    Table[data[[i, j]]
    , {i, 1, 4501}]
    , {j, 1, 61}];

AbsoluteTiming[
    extrctfast = Transpose[data];
]
```

> ```
> {0.013753,Null}
> ```

```
extrctfast == extrct
```

> ```
> True
> ```